# How to extract dates from a strign that contain may dates in php

Tags: php, regex

i tried thi is code

```
$temp = "1|<select class='form-control selectpicker' id='sel_date'
onchange='return GetSessionData(\"2\")'>
   <option>Select Date</option>
   <option value='2016/01/08'>08-Jan-2016</option>
   <option value='2016/01/09'>09-Jan-2016</option>
   <option value='2016/01/10'>10-Jan-2016</option>
   <option value='2016/01/11'>11-Jan-2016</option>
   <option value='2016/01/12'>12-Jan-2016</option>
   <option value='2016/01/13'>13-Jan-2016</option></select>";

   $_date_pattern_two = "/<option value=(/([a-zA-Z]+) (\d+)/>(.*?)/<\/option>";
   preg_match_all($_date_pattern_two, $temp, $_date_match_two);
   var_dump($_date_match_two);exit;
```

the out put i want array containig all the dates.
here

`$_date_match_two = ['08-Jan-2016','09-Jan-2016','10-Jan-2016','11-Jan-2016',..];`

Comment: Your question is not clear at all... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer:-

```
   preg_match_all("/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/", $temp, $match);
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($match[0]);exit;
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016/01/08
    [1] => 2016/01/09
    [2] => 2016/01/10
    [3] => 2016/01/11
    [4] => 2016/01/12
    [5] => 2016/01/13
)
```

Comment: I want output like this